# как редактировать class

Tags: java, компиляция, jar, декомпиляция, classloader

просто как в текстовом редакторе. только с компиляцией декомпиляцией. без зависимостей и библиотек. просто редактировать как txt. нужно в jar впихнуть отредактированный class. как редактировать class

можете просто сказать как редактировать

```
// Decompiled by DJ v3.12.12.96 Copyright 2011 Atanas Neshkov  Date: 27.08.2019 23:38:49
// Home Page: http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html  http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html - Check often for new version!
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   Freecam.java

package net.halalaboos.huzuni.mod.movement;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import com.mojang.authlib.GameProfile;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.Huzuni;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.event.EventManager;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.event.PlayerMoveEvent;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.mod.BasicMod;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.mod.Category;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.settings.Node;
import net.halalaboos.huzuni.api.settings.Value;
import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityOtherPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP;
import net.minecraft.client.multiplayer.WorldClient;

// Referenced classes of package net.halalaboos.huzuni.mod.movement:
//            Flight

public class Freecam extends BasicMod
{

private Freecam()
{
    super("Freecam", "Allows an individual to fly FROM THEIR BODY?", 22);
    oldFlying = false;
    setCategory(Category.MOVEMENT);
    setAuthor("Halalaboos");
    addChildren(new Node[] {
        speed
    });
}

public void toggle()
{
    super.toggle();
    if(mc.field_71439_g != null && mc.field_71441_e != null)
        if(isEnabled())
        {
            oldFlying = Flight.INSTANCE.isEnabled();
            fakePlayer = new EntityOtherPlayerMP(mc.field_71441_e, new GameProfile(mc.field_71439_g.func_110124_au(), mc.field_71439_g.func_70005_c_()));
            fakePlayer.func_82149_j(mc.field_71439_g);
            fakePlayer.field_71071_by = mc.field_71439_g.field_71071_by;
            fakePlayer.func_70080_a(mc.field_71439_g.field_70165_t, mc.field_71439_g.field_70163_u, mc.field_71439_g.field_70161_v, mc.field_71439_g.field_70177_z, mc.field_71439_g.field_70125_A);
            fakePlayer.field_70759_as = mc.field_71439_g.field_70759_as;
            mc.field_71441_e.func_73027_a(-69, fakePlayer);
            Flight.INSTANCE.setEnabled(true);
        } else
        {
            if(fakePlayer != null && mc.field_71439_g != null)
            {
                mc.field_71439_g.func_70080_a(fakePlayer.field_70165_t, fakePlayer.field_70163_u, fakePlayer.field_70161_v, fakePlayer.field_70177_z, fakePlayer.field_70125_A);
                mc.field_71441_e.func_73028_b(-69);
                Flight.INSTANCE.setEnabled(oldFlying);
            }
            if(mc.field_71439_g != null)
                Flight.INSTANCE.setEnabled(oldFlying);
        }
}

public void onEnable()
{
    huzuni.eventManager.addListener(this);
}

public void onDisable()
{
    huzuni.eventManager.removeListener(this);
}

@EventManager.EventMethod
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent event)
{
    mc.field_71439_g.func_70031_b(false);
    Flight.INSTANCE.setEnabled(true);
    if(fakePlayer != null)
        fakePlayer.func_70606_j(mc.field_71439_g.func_110143_aJ());
    event.setMotionX(event.getMotionX() * (double)speed.getValue());
    event.setMotionY(event.getMotionY() * (double)speed.getValue());
    event.setMotionZ(event.getMotionZ() * (double)speed.getValue());
}

public static final Freecam INSTANCE = new Freecam();
public final Value speed = new Value("Speed", "", 0.1F, 1.0F, 10F, "movement speed");
private boolean oldFlying;
private EntityOtherPlayerMP fakePlayer;

}
```

в это

```
// Decompiled by DJ v3.12.12.96 Copyright 2011 Atanas Neshkov  Date: 27.08.2019 23:38:10
// Home Page: http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html  http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html - Check often for new version!
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   FreecamHack.java

package net.wurstclient.forge.hacks;

import net.minecraft.client.Minecraft;
import net.minecraft.client.entity.EntityPlayerSP;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.RenderGlobal;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.GameSettings;
import net.minecraft.client.settings.KeyBinding;
import net.minecraft.network.play.client.CPacketPlayer;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.eventhandler.EventBus;
import net.wurstclient.fmlevents.*;
import net.wurstclient.forge.Category;
import net.wurstclient.forge.Hack;
import net.wurstclient.forge.settings.SliderSetting;
import net.wurstclient.forge.utils.EntityFakePlayer;
import net.wurstclient.forge.utils.KeyBindingUtils;

@Hack.DontSaveState
public final class FreecamHack extends Hack
{

public FreecamHack()
{
    super("Freecam", "Allows you to move the camera\nwithout moving your character.");
    speed = new SliderSetting("Speed", 1.0D, 0.050000000000000003D, 10D, 0.050000000000000003D, net.wurstclient.forge.settings.SliderSetting.ValueDisplay.DECIMAL);
    setCategory(Category.RENDER);
    addSetting(speed);
}

protected void onEnable()
{
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
    fakePlayer = new EntityFakePlayer();
    GameSettings gs = mc.field_71474_y;
    KeyBinding bindings[] = {
        gs.field_74351_w, gs.field_74368_y, gs.field_74370_x, gs.field_74366_z, gs.field_74314_A, gs.field_74311_E
    };
    KeyBinding akeybinding[] = bindings;
    int i = akeybinding.length;
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        KeyBinding binding = akeybinding[j];
        KeyBindingUtils.resetPressed(binding);
    }

}

protected void onDisable()
{
    MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.unregister(this);
    fakePlayer.resetPlayerPosition();
    fakePlayer.despawn();
    mc.field_71438_f.func_72712_a();
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onUpdate(WUpdateEvent event)
{
    EntityPlayerSP player = event.getPlayer();
    player.field_70159_w = 0.0D;
    player.field_70181_x = 0.0D;
    player.field_70179_y = 0.0D;
    player.field_70122_E = false;
    player.field_70747_aH = speed.getValueF();
    if(mc.field_71474_y.field_74314_A.func_151470_d())
        player.field_70181_x += speed.getValue();
    if(mc.field_71474_y.field_74311_E.func_151470_d())
        player.field_70181_x -= speed.getValue();
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onPlayerMove(WPlayerMoveEvent event)
{
    event.getPlayer().field_70145_X = true;
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onIsNormalCube(WIsNormalCubeEvent event)
{
    event.setCanceled(true);
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onSetOpaqueCube(WSetOpaqueCubeEvent event)
{
    event.setCanceled(true);
}

@SubscribeEvent
public void onPacketOutput(WPacketOutputEvent event)
{
    if(event.getPacket() instanceof CPacketPlayer)
        event.setCanceled(true);
}

private final SliderSetting speed;
private EntityFakePlayer fakePlayer;
}
```

Comment: "Просто как в текстовом редакторе" не получится. Это бинарные файлы со [строгим форматом](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html).

Comment: @sergey ну можно то хоть как то попытаться.

Comment: Можно изучить формат, ознакомиться с принципами работы виртуальной машины, особенно в части загрузки и верификации классов, а потом использовать полученные знания для написания программы, модифицирующей бинарник нужным образом, или взять hex-редактор и сделать это вручную.

Comment: Кстати, если jar-файл подписанный, то работать он после этого перестанет.

Comment: @sergey есть просто jar в нем class вытащил winrar`ом декомпилировал через dj java decompiler в jad редактировал. как jad компилировать в class

Comment: Файл с расширением jad - это просто метаданные. У вас в результате декомпиляции должен получиться файл с расширением java. Компилировать его потом так же, как и любой другой исходник - компилятором.

Comment: Если есть декомпилированный класс с изменениями, то компилировать можно в любой IDE воссоздав все зависимости классами/методами заглушками в отдельном проекте. Скомпилировать проект, вытащить скомпилированный клас из JAR'а и подменить им класс в исходном пакете. Теоретически возможно. Сам лично не пробовал.

Comment: @Rootware а более простой вариант без использование eclipse или itelijidea есть?

Comment: @Максим может быть и есть, но мне он не известен.

Comment: @Максим [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)